# Get the All The WebRequest Made by a selected Tab in Chrome A Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I want to get all the web request made by a tab and display it on the popup.html.

But the issue i am facing is.for eg. I opened a website in first tab and now I shift to second tab and open another site and shift back to first tab. So now when I shift back to first tab how can I get all the web request which was done by that website in the first tab previously before shifting the tab. So it will have to load again when I shift to the first tab.

I used below code to fetch the selected tab request

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){ 

    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {

      console.log(details);

    }, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. tabs.getSelected is [deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected) since Chrome 33, use `tabs.query`:

   ```
   var myTabId;
   chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
       myTabId = tabs[0].id;
   });
   ```
2. Check `tabId` in the callback of [onBeforeSendHeaders](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeSendHeaders):

   ```
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
       if (details.tabId == myTabId) {
           console.log(details);
       }
   });
   ```